# Avalondock MVVM Layout

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, avalondock, xceed

So The Question has been asked before [but not answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010308/avalondock-position-of-panes-in-mvvm) or [not answered the way I would like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033769/is-it-possible-to-prepare-bindable-mvvm-anchorable-panes-both-in-main-footer-an)

I know how to create the Layout I want to achive, using `LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup`, `LayoutAnchorablePane` and `LayoutDocument` in XAML, but I wanted to use Avalondock in a MVVM way, reducing my XAML to:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager" 
                                       DataContext="{Binding DockManagerViewModel}"
                                       DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}"
                                       AnchorablesSource="{Binding Anchorables}"
                                       Loaded="dockingManager_Loaded" 
                                       Unloaded="dockingManager_Unloaded">
```

Filling the `Documents` and `Anchorables` makes the desired windows appear in the dockingManager, but I don't see how I can secify the location in which they will appear.

How can I specify some rules ( prefferably in XAML ), to build a specific Layout, without loosing the MVVM separation?

E.G.: objects of Type A should all go togehter in a `LayoutAnchorablePane` on the right, Objects of type B all go together in a `LayoutAnchorablePane` on the left etc..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is quite a broad question and a number of answers except for those you quoted, like http://stackoverflow.com/a/32567244/2224701, or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239342/AvalonDock-and-MVVM

Comment: Yes, I have seen those. Link 1 is very useful to learn the general Avalondock MVVM approach, but it doesen't answer my question ( or I don't understand the answer), while I am not shure if link 2 is still relevant. Since it doesen't use `DataContext`, `DocumentSource` or `AnchorablesSoruce`, it might be a crutch to make the older Avalondock versions MVVM-compatible. I was hoping there might be a much easier way using AvalonDock 2.0.

Comment: So you have followed that CodePlex AvalonDock MVVM sample app approach and you have encountered some specific problem with Anchorables? `but I don't see how I can secify the place in which they will appear` - what exactly a `place` means ? You need to achieve some specific initial layout? Consider making your question a bit more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to the same situation. and found a solution which is tricky but works for me.

Followed the [Solution on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/719143/AvalonDock-2-0-Tutorial-Part-5-Load-Save-Layout-wi) and implimented save and load the layout.

note that for the first time when the application starts it does not have the layout so you need to create a XML with your desired layout and later on you can load the saved layout. hope this helps.

Example Docking Manager :

```
  <xcad:DockingManager x:Name="DockingManagerDockView"
                         AnchorablesSource="{Binding AnchorableSource}" 
                         DocumentsSource="{Binding DocumentSource}" 
                         Utility:AvalonDockLayoutSerializer.SaveLayoutCommand="{Binding SaveLayoutCommandOnExit}"
                         Utility:AvalonDockLayoutSerializer.LoadLayoutCommand="{Binding LoadLayoutCommand}">       
    <xcad:DockingManager.Theme>
        <xcad:MetroTheme />
    </xcad:DockingManager.Theme>
    <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
        <Pane:LayoutInitializer/>
    </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
    <xcad:DockingManager.Resources>            
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ExplorerViewModel}">
            <Views:ExplorerView />
        </DataTemplate>            
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:TableOfContentViewModel}">
            <Views:TableOfContentView x:Name="TOCView" Focusable="True">
                <Views:TableOfContentView.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="{Binding GridF5Command}"/>
                </Views:TableOfContentView.InputBindings>
            </Views:TableOfContentView>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:PropertyViewModel}">
            <Views:PropertyView />
        </DataTemplate>           
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SearchViewModel}">
            <Views:SearchPanel />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:DocumentViewModel}">
            <Views:DocumentView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ReIndexPanelViewModel}">
            <Views:ReIndexPanel />
        </DataTemplate>
    </xcad:DockingManager.Resources>       
    <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
        <Pane:PanesStyleSelector>
            <Pane:PanesStyleSelector.ToolStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutAnchorableItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Model.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Hidden}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
                    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="IconSource" Value="{Binding Model.IconSource}"/>
                </Style>
            </Pane:PanesStyleSelector.ToolStyle>
            <Pane:PanesStyleSelector.FileStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Model.FilePath}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}"/>
                    <Setter Property="CanClose" Value="False"/>                        
                </Style>
            </Pane:PanesStyleSelector.FileStyle>
        </Pane:PanesStyleSelector>
    </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
    <xcad:LayoutRoot>
        <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane Name="Explorer" DockMinWidth="250"/> 
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane Name="TOC" DockMinWidth="500"/>
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane Name="Property" DockMinWidth="300" />
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane Name="Search" DockMinWidth="300" />
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane Name="ReIndex" DockMinHeight="300" />
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
            <xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup >
                <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane/>
            </xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
        </xcad:LayoutPanel>            
    </xcad:LayoutRoot>
</xcad:DockingManager>
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen this, but I have one question to this solution: If you Add a new Document, how do you specify, in which DocumentPane it should be created?

Comment: Sorry, wanted to create new line, Enter Added the Comment :)

Comment: Ok thats fine i have added how my docking manager is done to the answer.

Comment: ok for that there is separate class in the solution called LayoutInitialize. that class says where your new document goes.

Comment: I suggest go to the EDI Solution and understand each part of the solution.

Comment: Edit: Ok, Thank you, my answer was too late :)

Comment: I still don't get it how to allocate certain `AnchorableSource` to the appropriated `LayoutAnchorablePane`. Anyone?

Comment: Sure. LayoutInitilizer is the one you need to look in to.